# How can I get the name (string) of a node from a data changed_notification in OPCUA?

Tags: opc-ua

I am new to opcua. I have a simple python3 client that I want to use to monitor a few voltages and currents from the opcua server.

I can subscribe to them and when they change, I can see the changed value but I don't know what the value is for.

I am trying to figure out how to use the info I know I can get like the node.nodeid.Identifier and use that to somehow get the path which is associated with the the id. That should tell me what the value is(?)

I thought it might be in the browse_name but that got me nowhere.

Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When your OPC UA Client want to get notified of the value update of a Node, it actually subscribe to the Attribute `Value` of this Node. You could try to subscribe to the Attribute `BrowseName` or `DisplayName` of the Node to get notified for the name.
You should then send a `CreateMonitoredItems` and set the corresponding `AttributeId` for each `iTemToMonitor`.

**However**, not every OPC UA Server support this feature.

Most OPC UA Client use the `Browse` and `Read` Services just before sending a `CreateSubscription`/`CreateMonitoredItems` in order to get the `BrowseName`/`DisplayName` or other attributes values they want.

Comment: Thanks @CamilleG. The suggestion of subscribing to the right attribute worked. I am able to get the node's name. The issue now is that many of the paths have the same end point:/State/Actual, /Voltage/Actual, /Current/Actual. So I can get the 'Actual' name but I can't figure out how to get the the parent node. Is that even correct? Is '/Voltage' the parent of '/Actual'?

Comment: That's why most OPC UA clients use the Browse Service before sending CreateMonitoredItems. You shall be able to send BrowseRequest with the NodeId of your Node and request its parent by asking for Inverse References. Parent Node shall have the Organize/OrganizedBy reference